# Laravel Routes not working, Apache configuration only allows for public/index.php/route

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel

Example:

```
Route::get('/get', function() {
    return 'get';
});
```

To view the route above, I must navigate to public/index.php/get.

I've viewed quite a few SO posts and googled around trying different things and it hasn't made a difference (yes I restart apache every time).

Here is my .htaccess in the public directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

# For all files not found in the file system, reroute the request to the
# "index.php" front controller, keeping the query string intact

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

What could be causing this still?  I'm running Ubuntu.

Comment: I just move `root/public/.htaccess to root/.htaccess` and it works

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Do you have mod_rewrite installed and enabled on apache? Try to remove the if lines ( and ) and see if it throws an error when you try to load the website. If it does, run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and restart apache.

This is the .htaccess I have on my public/ directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: sudo a2enmod rewrite
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Module rewrite already enabled

I'm not sure if I do have it enabled...  Where can I do that?

Comment: It seems it's installed and enabled. "Module rewrite already enabled". Can you try using my .htaccess?

Comment: You can search for "mod_rewrite" on the page generated with the PHP `phpinfo` function, or in the console on linux run the command: `apachectl -M` or the command (Centos and Fedora): `httpd -M` and search for "rewrite_module"

Answer (score 107):

Two most common causes of this behavior are:

1. mod_rewrite not enabled

   `sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart`
2. `AllowOverride` is set to None, set it to All, assuming Apache2.4

   `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

search for `<Directory /var/www/>` and change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`, then save the file and restart apache

Comment: There is no <Directory ...> in my apache2.conf.  An ls of /etc/apache2:

root@none:/etc/apache2# ls
apache2.conf            conf.d      mods-available   sites-enabled
apache2.conf.dpkg-dist  envvars     mods-enabled
conf-available          httpd.conf  ports.conf
conf-enabled            magic       sites-available
root@none:/etc/apache2#

Comment: Yeah it is inside the apache2.conf file. But your problem got resolved already. Have a nice day!

Comment: I just enable rewrite_module and worked like a charm!

Comment: This helped me out even a year and a half later. Thanks! :)

Comment: You should really override `AllowOverride` in the VirtualHost configuration found in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

Comment: Works for me enabling rewrite module

Answer (score 7):

In the **Apache Configuration file** may be located at */etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf* (location and names varies on server), provide AllowOverride permission for .htaccess file by updating the directory as follows:

```
<Directory "/var/www/laravel-sample-project/public">
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

This may solve your problem on laravel routes.

Also ensure that you're providing access "AllowOverride All" limited to directories, such as mentioned above and limited to the directory */var/www/laravel-sample-project/public* (mentioned here is the root directory for my project which may varies for you)

Answer (score 5):

Changing `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` and `sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload` did help.

Comment: You should really override that in the VirtualHost configuration found in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question, but for people coming from search engines:

Although the apache site config I had enabled (`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sitename.conf`) had `AllowOverride All`

But for some reason the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file had `AllowOverride None` for `/var/www/` directory.

#### Solution:

1. Run `nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
2. Find `Directory /var/www/` (on mac you can ctrl+w, paste the text and hit enter)
3. Inside it, change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

So, this

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

becomes this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use a .htaccess file, you need to specify the directory for your redirections:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On

     <Directory /home/vitela/laravel/public>
      RewriteBase /public
      RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L,QSA]
     </Directory>
  </IfModule>
```

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

Comment: @MohamedRaza check the syntax of your Apache config (apachectl configtest) and that the routes you entered are valid.

Comment: where can i check the syntax of apache config?

Answer (score 0):

In MacOs. The Main problem of .htaccess not working is there is not mod_rewrite.so enabled in httpd.conf file of apache configuration.
i have solved this by uncomment the line :

## LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so

Remove the # from above line httpdf.conf. Then it will works. enjoy!