# Laravel 5 deployment on xampp routes not working

Tags: laravel-5

Alright so after looking around online forever trying to figure out why this isn't working I decided to ask this. 
I did everything I needed to do such as editing the config file for xampp. This is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Referring to this [Laravel Routes not working, Apache configuration only allows for public/index.php/route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784606/laravel-routes-not-working-apache-configuration-only-allows-for-public-index-ph)
I followed all these and everything seems to be configured correctly, it's just not working for all my other routes. What could be the problem?

Updates:
After doing some installation tests I saw that I made a simple mistake when installing laravel.
I decided to just reinstall laravel and place my app into it. The routes appear to be functioning.
Right now my xampp server has /htdocs/laravel/ and /htdocs/laravel-test/ where the root directory would be [hostname.com]/laravel-test/