# How to deploy a Laravel app in a certain directory?

Tags: laravel, apache

I have finished my beautiful Laravel app let's call it `Beautiful` on my development PC. So its now time to put in a productive environment.

We're using Apache, and I've been told that my app must be under `/var/apache/html/projects/Beautiful`, so I transferred the app (using Git), ran composer and npm, and such. I already changed the .env file so it connects to the production postgres database and such.

Even the index page is working in `http:://ourserver/Beautiful/public` and here it comes my problem.

What else do I have to configure in order that it runs without the `/public`? The problem is that obviously all routes doesn't work with public, for example `http://ourserver/Beautiful/public/login` doesn't work, or any other.

Is it a thing of Apache's configuration, or there's something in Laravel I can do?

I know the correct thing to do would be to create a virtual host in Apache that points to Beautiful.ourserver.com, but I have no control on the DNS, all I can do is work from ourserver.

Comment: It’s a simple Apache configuration. You just need to make it point to that directory (`public`), but you could post it here for us to help you out.

Comment: Like an alias? Or as a virtial host?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Routes not working, Apache configuration only allows for public/index.php/route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784606/laravel-routes-not-working-apache-configuration-only-allows-for-public-index-ph)

Comment: Not remotely...

Comment: A virutal host yes, then you won’t need to change any Laravel boilerplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you should follow the path below.
put everything in the public folder into `/var/apache/html/projects/Beautiful`, then put all laravel folders and files into `/var/apache/html/{somewhere}`. Now edit `/var/apache/html/projects/Beautiful/index.php` and edit like this,
    - `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` to `require __DIR__.'/../{somewhere}/vendor/autoload.php';`
    - `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` to `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../{somewhere}/bootstrap/app.php';';`
    and add below after this `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../{somewhere}/bootstrap/app.php';';`
    - `$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});`

Comment: Yeah after banging my head all morning I found an article that described this, as usual, I was doing some other things at the time, so looks like one problem hidden another. Thank you very much.

The article I'm talking about is: https://laravel-news.com/subfolder-install