# Why only home page route working on live server?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I have setup on host my 5.4 Laravel project.Everything used to work just fine but now when i try to access any page other then homepage i get 404 not found even when i want to access phpmyadmin panel ([www.mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin](http://www.mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin)).Is this a .htaccess config problem or something wrong with the server or domain ?
this is my .htaccess file content :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220967/discussion-on-question-by-youssef-boudaya-why-only-home-page-route-working-on-li).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the apache config to accept what is written in .htaccess file. This would help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784606/laravel-routes-not-working-apache-configuration-only-allows-for-public-index-ph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784606/laravel-routes-not-working-apache-configuration-only-allows-for-public-index-ph#:%7E:text=Do%20you%20have%20mod_rewrite%20installed,a2enmod%20rewrite%20and%20restart%20apache.&text=Changing%20AllowOverride%20None%20to%20AllowOverride,%26%26%20sudo%20%2Fetc%2Finit.)