# Request routes not found after change in .htaccess in Cpanel Laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, cpanel

Request routes aren't found after I made a change in the .htaccess file within Cpanel. Below is my .htaccess file, which redirects to the /public folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?omnisnco.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?omnisnco.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L]
```

And after doing this, my request routes are not being found!

**Error message**

> The requested URL was not found on this server. An error was
> encountered while trying to use an `ErrorDocument` to handle the
> request.

Answer (score -1):

Could you see the logs?
`/var/log/apache/access.log` or in `/var/log/apache2/access.log`
The details could help you debug the error.

Based on this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24784890/12060921), you can try these lines:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```