# My Laravel .htaccess rule seems incorrect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-8

My website worked fine until I installed SSL certificate. Now my website displays:
**Forbidden**

**You don't have permission to access this resource.**

**Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) Port 443**

My Apache configuration file and virtual host point to **mysite-files.com/public** directory.

I've checked the directory and subdirectory permission settings of /var/www/html. It's 0755, while for files it's 0644.

My site's SSL checker checks out as valid.
whynopadlock.com checks mysite.com as enforcing HTTPS.
Yet, I still can't get mysite.com to display again.

I've restarted Apache and my VPS. Still, no joy.

That's why I believe .htaccess file is the culprit.

This is my .htaccess content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    #RewriteEngine On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.com/$1 [R,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Help, please

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272557/laravel-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

Comment: @ - Aqib Javed. I tried the solutions on in that thread. None worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution on this thread.
[Editing Apache2 configuration file and inclusion in .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784606/laravel-routes-not-working-apache-configuration-only-allows-for-public-index-ph#:%7E:text=Do%20you%20have%20mod_rewrite%20installed,a2enmod%20rewrite%20and%20restart%20apache.&text=Changing%20AllowOverride%20None%20to%20AllowOverride,%26%26%20sudo%20%2Fetc%2Finit.)

Worked like a charm.

Comment: you marked other question as correct and comment "doesn't work"...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

Try using this code in your .htaccess file, this works for laravel 9

Comment: i tried writing the rewrite rule in module condition but it still didn't work.

Comment: remove answer because user comment the fix